# Fitting cell growth model (Monod) with 3 PDEs in R

Tags: r, least-squares, data-fitting, pde, model-fitting

**Updated** The problem is solved with the answer from @tpetzoldt, the original code has been modified to run the fit successfully.

**Hi everybody, I'm trying to fit the experimental data on a set of 3 PDEs to find 4 coefficients including mumax, Ks, Y_(x/s), and Y_(p/s). The code I used worked with the set of 2 PDEs but is not working with this set of 3. The following is the code:**

**The set of PDEs needs to be fitted:**

dX/dt = mumax . S . X / (Ks + S)

dS/dt = -1/Y_(x/s) . mumax . S . X / (Ks + S)

dP/dt = alpha . dX/dt + beta . X

```
library(deSolve)
library(ggplot2) 
library(minpack.lm) 
library(reshape2)

time <- c(0, 3, 5, 8, 9.5, 11.5, 14, 16, 18, 20, 25, 27)
X <- c(0.0904, 0.1503, 0.2407, 0.3864, 0.5201, 0.6667, 0.8159, 0.9979, 1.0673, 1.1224, 1.1512, 1.2093)
S <- c(9.0115, 8.8088, 7.9229, 7.2668, 5.3347, 4.911, 3.5354, 1.4041, 0, 0, 0, 0)
P <- c(0.0151, 0.0328, 0.0621, 0.1259, 0.2949, 0.3715, 0.4199, 0.522, 0.5345, 0.6081, 0.07662, 0.7869)
data <- data.frame(time, X, S, P)

Monod <- function(t,c,parms) {
  k1 <- parms$k1 # mumax
  k2 <- parms$k2 # Ks
  k3 <- parms$k3 # Y_(X/S)
  k4 <- parms$k4 # alpha
  k5 <- parms$k5 # beta
  r <- numeric(length(c))
  r[1] <-  k1 * c["S"] * c["X"] / ( k2 + c["S"] ) # r[1] = dCx/dt = k1.Cs.Cx/(k2+Cs)
  r[2] <- -k1 * c["S"] * c["X"] / ( ( k2 + c["S"] ) * k3 ) # r[2] = dCs/dt = -1/k3 * dCx/dt 
  r[3] <-  k4 * r[1] + k5 * c["X"] # r[3] = dCp/dt = alpha * dX/dt + beta * X
  return(list(r))       
}

residuals <- function(parms){
  cinit <- c( X=data[1,2], S=data[1,3], P=data[1,4] )
  
  t <- c(seq(0, 27, 1), data$time)
  t <- sort(unique(t))
  
  k1 <- parms[1]
  k2 <- parms[2]
  k3 <- parms[3]
  k4 <- parms[4]
  k5 <- parms[5]
  
  out <- ode( y = cinit, 
              times = t, 
              func = Monod, 
              parms = list( k1 = k1, k2 = k2, k3 = k3, k4 = k4, k5 = k5) )
  
  out_Monod <- data.frame(out)
  out_Monod <- out_Monod[out_Monod$t %in% data$time,]
  
  pred_Monod <- melt(out_Monod,id.var="time",variable.name="Substance",value.name="Conc")
  exp_Monod <- melt(data,id.var="time",variable.name="Substance",value.name="Conc")
  residuals <- pred_Monod$Conc-exp_Monod$Conc
  
  return(residuals)
}

parms <- c(k1=0.5, k2=6.5, k3=0.2, k4=1.2, k5 = 0.1)
fitval <- nls.lm(par=parms,fn=residuals)
cinit <- c(X=data[1,2], S=data[1,3], P=data[1,4])
out <- ode(y=cinit, times=seq(min(data$time), max(data$time)), func = Monod, parms=as.list(coef(fitval)))
plot(out, obs=data, mfrow=c(1, 3))
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please trim it more, down to the minimum possible. Then it is likely that you find the programming error yourself. The model integration shows a warning in the first call of `ode` so it is unlikely that the rest will run through.

Comment: Another issue: the system of equations shown in the introduction does not match the equations in the code. Are you sure you want a PDE system and not just ODEs?

Comment: Those in the code match the equations. I have corrected the equations for more clarity. I didn't find any error when running the function Monod2. I'll try to trim it more.

Comment: The system of equations has no derivative at the RHS, but the 3rd equation in the code and its comment has.

Comment: Hi Cuong, it makes it MUCH easier for people to follow and reply to your code if you remove lines which have no effect on the running of the program like ``summary(fitval)`` and ``parest`` - removing them would increase your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Thanks @user438383 for your recommendation. I'm a newbie on StackOverflow therefore there're lots of things to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code had several issues:

- the state variables were lower case in the data, upper case in the model and without any name in the initial values
- time was called `t` in the data and `time` in the ode output
- concentration had the name `Concentration` in one place and `conc` in another
- The names `ssq` and `ssqres` were misleading as the function calculates the residuals and not the square and not a sum. The sum of squares is calculated in the background (see `?nls.lm`)
- the assignment operators `<-` and `=` were inconsistently used. This is not an error, but not really good style.
- instead of artificial names `k1, K2, ...` one can directly use original names like `mumax` or `alpha`.
- It is not clear why names like `data2` or `Monod2` were used as there was no `data1`.

Fixing all this, we come to the solution below. It runs through and fits somehow, but it can still be improved. The warnings may be ignored for now. The reason is, that parameters exceed the allowed range. This can of course be fixed but would be another question.

```r
library(deSolve)
library(ggplot2) 
library(minpack.lm)
library(reshape2)

data <- data.frame(
  time = c(0, 3, 5, 8, 9.5, 11.5, 14, 16, 18, 20, 25, 27),
  X = c(0.0904, 0.1503, 0.2407, 0.3864, 0.5201, 0.6667, 0.8159, 0.9979, 1.0673, 1.1224, 1.1512, 1.2093),
  S = c(9.0115, 8.8088, 7.9229, 7.2668, 5.3347, 4.911, 3.5354, 1.4041, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  P = c(0.0151, 0.0328, 0.0621, 0.1259, 0.2949, 0.3715, 0.4199, 0.522, 0.5345, 0.6081, 0.07662, 0.7869)
)

Monod <- function(t, c, parms) {
  k1 <- parms$k1 # mumax
  k2 <- parms$k2 # Ks
  k3 <- parms$k3 # Y_(X/S)
  k4 <- parms$k4 # alpha
  k5 <- parms$k4 # beta
  r <- numeric(length(c))
  r[1] <-  k1 * c["S"] * c["X"] / (k2 + c["S"])
  r[2] <- -k1 * c["S"] * c["X"] / ((k2 + c["S"]) * k3)
  r[3] <-  k4 * r[1] + k5 * c["X"]
  return(list(r))       
}

cinit <- c(X = data[1, 2], S = data[1, 3], P = data[1, 4])
t <- seq(0, 27, 1)
parms <- list(k1=0.1, k2=5, k3=1, k4=0.08, k5 = 0.005)

out <- ode(y=cinit, times=t, func = Monod, parms=parms)
plot(out)

residuals <- function(parms){
  cinit <- c(X = data[1, 2], S = data[1, 3], P = data[1, 4] )
  
  # time points for which conc is reported including the points where data is available
  t <- c(seq(0, 27, 1), data$t)
  t <- sort(unique(t))
  
  # parameters from the parameter estimation routine:
  k1 <- parms[1]
  k2 <- parms[2]
  k3 <- parms[3]
  k4 <- parms[4]
  
  # solve ODE for a given set of parameters
  out <- ode(y = cinit, times = t, func = Monod, parms = list( k1 = k1, k2 = k2, k3 = k3, k4 = k4) )
  
  # Filter data that contains time points where data is available:
  out_Monod <- data.frame(out)
  out_Monod <- out_Monod[out_Monod$t %in% data$t,]
  
  # Evaluate predicted vs experimental residual
  pred_Monod <- melt(out_Monod, id.var="time", variable.name="Substance", value.name="conc")
  exp_Monod  <- melt(data, id.var="time", variable.name="Substance", value.name="conc")
  residuals  <- pred_Monod$conc - exp_Monod$conc
  
  # return predicted vs experimental residual
  return(residuals)
}

# initial guess for parameters
parms <- c(k1=0.5, k2=6.5, k3=0.2, k4=1.2)
fitval <- nls.lm(par=parms, fn=residuals)
summary(fitval)

out <- ode(y=cinit, times=seq(min(data$time), max(data$time)), func = Monod, parms=as.list(coef(fitval)))
plot(out, obs=data, mfrow=c(1, 3))
```

[image: fitted model]

Comment: Thanks so much for your correction and clarification @tpetzoldt. May I suggest the code would be perfect with a small correction of `t <- c(seq(0, 27, 1), data$time)`

Comment: You mean `t <- sort(unique(c(seq(0, 27, 1), data$time)))`? Otherwise time steps will be out of order. These time steps are already used within the `residuals` function, while the time steps at the first place are only for testing of the Monod function. I changed it now to `seq(0, 27, 0)` , so that it becomes independent of the time step in the data. The result is the same.